# ParseQueryAdapter : sort data on client side

Tags: sorting, parse-platform, baseadapter

My problem is quite simple, but my code is not working.
I want to sort result of a ParseQuery into the ParseQueryAdapter before display it into a ListView.

```
products.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<Product>() {

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(List<Product> data, Exception e) {
            Collections.sort(data, LastDealComparator);
            products.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

    });
```

I checked in debugger data is sorted by the Comparator ... but not updated into the ParseQueryAdapter ... notifyDataSetInvalidated do nothing.

For information, initially my problem is to sort a query on a pointer field :

```
query.orderByDescending("deal.date");
```

But that's not working too ... so i write a manual sort.

Comment: Got the same problem

Comment: Dont know if there is a feature like this in the framework you are are working with but on swift you could do something like "query.orderByDescending("deal.date");" usign "whereKey:matchesQuery:".

Answer (score 0):

You can create the onLoaded event and create the sort index (sort of HashMap)

```
@Override
public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e)
```

And in the getItem function you can map the data based on the index.

Example of a reverse order list:

```
@Override
public ParseObject getItem(int position) { //For descending order
    return super.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}
```